# Pull data from a PHP object

Tags: php, object

I am trying to pull data from a PHP object, but I can't get all the data which is needed.

Object `$hotel1` is:

```
stdClass Object ( 
[processId] => HH-24896940 
[hotelCode] => TRN367 
[availabilityStatus] => InstantConfirmation 
[totalPrice] => 398 
[totalTax] => 0 
[totalSalePrice] => 0 
[currency] => EUR 
[boardType] => Half Board 
[rooms] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( 
[roomCategory] => Double Standard [paxes] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [paxType] => Adult [age] => 30 ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( 
[paxType] => Adult [age] => 30 ) ) 
[totalRoomRate] => 398 
[ratesPerNight] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( 
[date] => 2015-01-27 
[amount] => 398 ) ) ) ) )
```

Code used is :

```
<?php
  foreach ($availHotels as $hotel1) {
        if ($hotel1->hotelCode === $code1) {
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

And I pull data with:

```
  $hotel1->boardType , $hotel1->totalPrice
```

But when I am trying to get `roomCategory` is not working with

```
$hotel1->roomCategory
```

Comment: first of all, it ain't an array, it's an object

Comment: Please read: http://php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php. (Give a man a fish -> he will eats it for 1 day, learn a man how to fish -> he will eats it forever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"roomCategory" is nested in "room".
Here is an example how to get what you expect:

```
$obj = (object) array(
    'boardType' => 'foo',
    'room' => array(
        (object) array(
            'roomCategory' => 'bar'
        )
    )
);

print_r($obj);

echo $obj->boardType;

echo $obj->room[0]->roomCategory;
```

$obj would be $hotel1 in your case.